# Android : Callback on insertion of microSD

Tags: android

Is there any callback mechanism on the Android SDK that will notify my application when I insert/remove a microSD card?

Thanks in advance,
Parth

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Intent for this. See the [ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED) and [ACTION_MEDIA_UNMOUNTED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_UNMOUNTED) Intent constants.

*For reference, I searched the web with the terms "android intent sd card insertion"*

**Edit**
You may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417161/android-intent-for-sdcard-ready) question and its answer more helpful; there's code and examples as well as further detail on the two constants I mentioned, `ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED` and `ACTION_MEDIA_UNMOUNTED`

Comment: As far as I can see Android never produces ACTION_MEDIA_UNMOUNTED Intent. Look at 758 - 763 lines in MountService.java [link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/483f3b06ea84440a082e21b68ec2c2e54046f5a6/services/java/com/android/server/MountService.java). Intent fired on 769 within sendStorageIntent().