# UI crashes after change from Charge Only to Disk Drive?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

It seems that apps, or maybe it's just my app, that have the following required permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

tend to *occasionally* crash the UI when for example you're running the app and then you decide to switch  from Charge Only to Disk Drive. The other thing is that the app becomes unavailable to the user when the user is on Disk Drive mode. You get the message : "The Linked program is no longer installed on your phone".

Is there a way to mitigate this issue, programmatically. Maybe, by checking when the user is on Disk Drive mode which should trigger the removal of the permissions or something similar. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a cursor adapter/content provider combination? You should be able to get broadcasts when the external storage is unmounted/mounted, and you could write some fall-back code. Are you installing your app on SDCARD?

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/apps-on-sd-card-details.html

[android intent for sdcard ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417161/android-intent-for-sdcard-ready)

See if these links help.

Comment: Yes I'm using preferExternal in my manifest, which installs the app on the SD card, could that be the reasone