# Android sdcard not perpared after the phone restart

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I encounter a strange thing about the android sdcard in my HTC Desire S,
I have one application which has the some actions to sdcard in the onCreate function,
and this application will be start when phone boot.

Now I installed this application, and restart the Phone,
when the phone restarted, my application crashed, i find it caused by the sdcard is null.
I have no idea about it. Is my fault? or the android not prepared the sdcard before the application stared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wait that the sdcard is mounted with `ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED` in your intent.

When the phone starts, it can take some times before the sdcard is ready (filesystem checks, errors recovering etc.)

Comment: why the android system start application after the sdcard is ready?

Comment: `Common.HOME_DIRECTORY = ctx.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath() + Common.ADVERTISE_DIRECTORY;`
In my application onCreate, and i found the ctx.getExternalFilesDir(null) is null.

Comment: I suggest you to add a BroadcastReceiver in your app, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417161/android-intent-for-sdcard-ready.

Implement this before any interaction with the sdcard (above the 'getExternalFilesDir()')