# Android BroadCast Receiver Thread to notify sd card removal

Tags: java, android, multithreading, broadcastreceiver, android-sdcard

I need help implementing a broadcast receiver that will run on a seperate thread started through an activity to notify SDCard Removal or unmounting. Can someone guide me on this please

Thank you

Comment: what all have you tried till now?

Comment: I've just gone through a few examples but they don't seem to be doing what I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create Intent Filter:

```
 <receiver android:name="Receiver " >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_MEDIA_REMOVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Activity to notify SDCard Removal or unmounting

Here is the check:

```
Boolean isSDPresent = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);

if(isSDPresent)
{
  // Do something
}
else
{
 // trigger the broadcast!!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417161/android-intent-for-sdcard-ready) , it tells you how to use broadcast receivers for media mount event which you can extend for your purpose (which is to listen for media unmount). And then you should register filters for all the events you want to receive, like [ACTION_MEDIA_BAD_REMOVAL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_BAD_REMOVAL), [ACTION_MEDIA_EJECT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_EJECT), [ACTION_MEDIA_REMOVED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_REMOVED) and [ACTION_MEDIA_UNMOUNTED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_UNMOUNTED).